# What is this concrete slab in my front yard?

Tags: concrete

House was built in 1964. Slab is about 3 feet across.
[image]

Comment: See https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/91102/18078 if not in current use (sewer system added between 1964 and now)

Comment: Your town may have a record of this. Or the local  "Dig Safe" folks might.

Comment: It's almost certainly some sort of manhole.  It may be an access to a septic tank or a rainwater-collecting cistern.

Comment: If you open it, the mole people will emerge.

Comment: While highly unlikely in a residential setting, our church's kitchen has a cover like that for the grease pit.

Comment: Obviously this is where the Morlocks take the Eloi to their dinner parties.

Comment: @SteveSh that makes for a totally valid answer rather than a comment.

Comment: I hope you come back and tell us what you found underneath it!

Answer (score 23):

*Most likely* access to a septic system, or sewer sump.

*Impossible to say for sure* without gathering some hefty help and picking it off, or consulting old documents about your house. It covers *something* and was evidently meant to be findable and removable, but not easily removable (don't want kids falling in whatever it is.)

*Or, the mid 1960's being what they were, perhaps there's an old fallout shelter under there ;^)*

**Standard Warning** to not so much as stick your head in to whatever is under there without thorough venting, though you probably would not be so inclined for the most likely case.

If it's an actively used septic system, go ahead and have it pumped out, since that has obviously not been done in your memory.

Comment: A fallout shelter is possible, but it would need to be easier access.

Comment: Might have been made less easy access when it was considered more of a potential liability than an advantage.

Answer (score 8):

My guess is its a Concrete Septic/Cistern cover. Try lifting it up, there may be a tank underneath...

Comment: If it's about three feet across, it probably weighs around 250 pounds.  Lifting it could be a bit of a challenge.

Comment: @Mark The two lifting points are clearly intended for it to be hoisted mechanically. An enterprising backyard engineer could no doubt rig up something, but the original intention was probably to use a backhoe.

Comment: 2-4 burly septic service persons and a couple of hooks (or long bars) would do it. This sort of thing is specifically intended NOT to be easily moved by one person, with the intent of keeping curious children out.